# What is the best way to filter or otherwise manipulate the results returned by a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

Often I find myself wanting to filter or order the results returned by `exec`ing a stored procedure - for example to order the output of `sp_who2` by login or CPU Time, or filter it by host name. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible solution is to put the result set into a temp table and select from it. Here is an example for sp_who2: [SQL Server: Filter output of sp_who2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234691/sql-server-filter-output-of-sp-who2)

Answer (score 2):

I love the [SMSToolpack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/). its a free download and lets you sort the resulting grid of any sql query you run.

On top of that, you can search the data just like searching for a text string in excel.

it helps format you SQL text and makes it look pretty so you can be proud of your SQL code and much more...

The best thing i think is it lets you color code windows to specific servers so its simple to know when you are running code on dev vs prod